# Summation notation $ 1 + \frac{1}{1+2} + \frac{1}{1+2+3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{1+2+3 + \ldots +n} + \ldots $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to write the sum
$$
 1 + \frac{1}{1+2} + \frac{1}{1+2+3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{1+2+3 + \ldots +n} + \ldots
  $$
in summation (∑) notation.There are 2 series here, one the entire 1 + (1/1+2)... series and the other one in denominator of each term. This summation is a sub-part of a Induction problem.

Comment: Notice that $1+2+\ldots + k$ is just the $k$:th Triangular number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$$ which is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{T_n}$$
$T_n$ being the $n^{th}$ triangle number.

Clearly, it converges to $2$. This is because the sequence is equivalent to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n+1}$$ which is telescoping.

Comment: How it converges to 2, can you explain ?

Comment: It telescopes - the sequence simplifies down to $(\frac{2}{1} - \frac{2}{2})+(\frac{2}{2} - \frac{2}{3})+(\frac{2}{3} - \frac{2}{4})...$

Comment: thanks @merelymyself

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^i j}$$

You can calculate $a_i=\sum_{j=1}^i j$ first, then represent $\frac{1}{a_i}=b_{i}-b_{i-1}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-b_{i-1})=b_n-b_0$.